# PAYPAL payment gateway "Billing Phone is a required field." issue in woocomerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, checkout, billing, form-fields

I am working on a woocomerce project that has Paypal as one of the payment gateway options.
Here I am using **WooCommerce PayPal Payments** plugin by **WooCommerce** for integration.

Now while I am testing, it gives billing form field error on checkout page. If I deactivate the plugin or use any different payment method it works perfectly well!

I am sharing some screenshots and live project link here. Thank you in advance for your help.

https://folksbangla.com/

[image: the issue is here]

Comment: The field's validation does not accept that phone number input.

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX thank you for the reply, Is this caused by the paypal plugin I used here? How to solve it? any suggesstions?

Comment: It could be. And it may also not be a number/format PayPal accepts.

Comment: Got the answer, it causes for another plugin that I have used to display Country Codes and Paypal don't support INR currency so it will not work in my country as a payment gateway.